# How to read and print JSON array elements

Tags: json

I am trying to read the Json Objects and Arrays by below java program

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
public class App {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      //Creating a JSONParser object
      JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
      try {
         //Parsing the contents of the JSON file
         JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\json\\CredirRisk_corainputtoIIB.json"));
         //Forming URL
         System.out.println("Contents of the JSON are: ");
         System.out.println("Target: "+jsonObject.get("target"));
         System.out.println("Source: "+jsonObject.get("source"));
         System.out.println("Request Tracker Id: "+jsonObject.get("request_tracker_id"));
         System.out.println("Request Date And Timestamp: "+ jsonObject.get("request_datetimestamp"));
        // System.out.println("Place of birth: "+ jsonObject.get("Place_Of_Birth"));
        // System.out.println("Salary: "+jsonObject.get("Salary"));
         //Retrieving the array
         JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("AccountCreditrisk");
         System.out.println("");
         System.out.println("AccountCreditrisk details: ");
         //Iterating the contents of the array
         Iterator<String> iterator = jsonArray.iterator();
         while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println((String)iterator.next());
         }
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

When I tried to execute the above java program, I am getting output as below:

Contents of the JSON are:
Target: SUS
Source: CORA
Request Tracker Id: 201013051429
Request Date And Timestamp: 2020-10-13 05:14:29

AccountCreditrisk details:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at com.techwave.reusejson.App.main(App.java:33)

It is not able to read AccountCreditrisk array elements. Can you please help me on this ?

The original JSON file is as follows:

```
{
    "target": "SUS",
    "source": "CORA",
    "request_tracker_id": "201013051429",
    "request_datetimestamp": "2020-10-13 05:14:29",
    "AccountCreditrisk": [{
        "risk_code": null,
        "payment_terms": null,
        "op_code": "056",
        "global_collector": null,
        "credit_analyst": "CRDAB000",
        "account_key": "USBL056155266B"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements of the array aren't strings; they are JSON objects whose properties are strings.  You already know how to get individual elements of a JSON object.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am new to Java. Can you please provide me with a solution for the above Json where I can retrieve the AccountCreditrisk array elements with key value pairs from the Json file above ? It would be a great help to me.